# What causes POCO proxy entities to only sometimes be created in Entity Framework 4

Tags: proxy, entity-framework-4, poco

I have set up my POCOs and I have marked their public properties as virtual and I am successfully getting Proxies most of the time (95%) but randomly I am getting EF return some proxies and some non-proxies.

Recycling the app pool when this happens will then fix this instance of the error and it will go away for an amount of time. Then it will re-occur in some other random (it seems) place.

What can cause this sort of behaviour?

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/36c95af3c7.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/36c95af3c7.jpg)

Thanks, Kohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it (im getting in the habit of almost giving up, posting here and then solving it)

Anyway, when I was adding a new Question i was using something like `var q = new Question()` this was then being stored as a non-proxy. In the end i found out by creating a new Question on the ObjectContext like so `var q = ObjectContext.CreateObject<Question>();` causes it to be a proxy and works just fine and dandy.

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers,
Kohan.

A helpful source : [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20221231072511/https://web.archive.org/web/20160604124231/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/10/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-3-change-tracking-with-poco.aspx) (read the comments)