# why my poco entity isn't a proxy?

Tags: entity-framework, poco, entity-framework-ctp5, proxy-classes

I can't figure out the reason of the strange behaviour of my entity. 
I'm using POCO classes generated from the database with the dbContext template introduced with the CTP5. 
In my DbContext I have several entities and when I use them, they are proxies except one. This entity was generated as the others and it has only 3 simple attributes. 
I found a thread related [What causes POCO proxy entities to only sometimes be created in Entity Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044378/what-causes-poco-proxy-entities-to-only-sometimes-be-created-in-entity-framework), but all my entities were added with the new keyword, I never use the CreateObject for any object.

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.ID = "ID";
customer .Name = "Name";
repository.add(customer);
repository.Save();
```

Why only it isn't a proxy?
I checked also the requirements to be a proxy defined here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx and the properties that I should define in my entity model and all follows the guidelines.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the ADO.NET blog I found an article where they say: "if the entity type is sealed and/or has no virtual properties then Create will just create an instance of the entity type", so I think that's the reason why my entity with only simple attributes is not a proxy. If I'm wrong, I appreciated others point of view.

Comment: With "simple attributes" you mean scalar properties (int, string, double, etc.) and no navigation properties, right? Are those properties `virtual`? If not, I think that's indeed the reason why you don't get proxy objects. Simply make your properties virtual to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, you got it! I mean scalar properties. No, these properties aren't virtual, but why the DbContext POCO generator makes virtual only the Navigation properties or the complex(object) properties? You think that's correct leave the scalar properties as no virtual? It's not a need to have them as a proxy, I want to understand if it's better to have as. Thanks!